# how to get value of key in php associative array by comparing key with a string to get value?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have below small PHP script, I just need the value from the array if I provide key in `$str`.

```
$empid_array = array('CIP004 - Rinku Yadav', 'CIP005 - Shubham Sehgal');

$key = array();
$value = array();

$str = "CIP004";

foreach($empid_array as $code){

  $str = preg_split("/\-/", $code);
  array_push($key, $str[0]);
  array_push($value, $str[1]); 
}

$combined = array_combine($key, $value);

echo count($combined);

foreach($combined as $k => $v){
    if($str == $k){
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `trim` on the `$str[x]` as they have a space.

Comment: Also use explode, there's no need for regular expressions here.

Comment: What @miken32 said as you can explode on space-space

Comment: hi, but still not clear as no result shown on if condition check, I used both explode and trim solutions

Comment: but on array_combine() an associative array is formed but if I want to get the value of key such as $str by this==>>> echo $combined[$str]; then no result shown to me

Comment: I tried this way <?php

$empid_array = array('CIP004 - Rinku Yadav', 'CIP005 - Shubham Sehgal');

$key = array();
$value = array();

$str = 'CIP004';

foreach($empid_array as $code){
    
    $str = explode("-",$code);
   array_push($key, $str[0]);
  array_push($value, $str[1]); 
}

$combined = array_combine($key, $value);

echo count($combined);

echo $combined[$str];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code considerably here. Step one, use `array_walk` to walk through the array and build the `$combined` array. Step two, there's no point in looping through the array, just access the value by the index:

```
$empid_array = ['CIP004 - Rinku Yadav', 'CIP005 - Shubham Sehgal'];
$str = "CIP004";
$combined = [];
// passing $combined by reference so we can modify it
array_walk($empid_array, function ($e) use (&$combined) {
    list($id, $name) = explode(" - ", $e);
    $combined[$id] = $name;
});

echo $combined[$str] ?? "Not found";
```